# повесить обработчик fileupload на все элементы документа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я устанавливаю обработчик загрузки файла на все элементы.

```
$(".uploads_files_answers").fileupload({
dataType: 'json',
progressInterval: 10,
progressall: function (e, data) {
    $('#progress .file-load-bar').css('width', '100%');
},
error: error_file_downloading,
done: function (e, data) {  
     console.log('Select file')
     }
});
```

Потом динамически удаляю и добавляю элелменты.

```
let file_input_elements = $(".uploads_files_answers")
file_input_elements.remove()
file_input_elements.appendTo(main_form)
```

Обработчик тоже удаляется.
Можно ли установить обработчик таки образом, чтобы он "навесился" на все file_input_elements не удалялся при удалении элементов и добавлялся при добавлении новых.

Answer (score 0):

при добавлении нового элемента навешивайте на него обработчик. само оно добавляться не умеет.

Comment: монжно же повесить обработчик на документ. $(document).on('click', '.uploads_files_answers', function (){}). И тогда обработчики будут  срабатывать на новодобвленные элелменты. без явного навешивания.